# Splitting a string in Python to fill column in Excel

Tags: python, string

I have an Excel sheet with random columns (TABLE_ID, STEP_TYPE, STEP_ID etc...).  One column contains SQL Statements (SQL_STRING) for dropping/creating/inserting records into tables, one row per SQL statement.  Each SQL statement is identified by StepID, stored in another column, starting at 1.

StepID = 1 is always the DROP TABLE xxx statement.

I have a new column called 'TEST_TABLE_NM'.  What I want to do is populate the name of the table in this column based on the contents in the DROP TABLE statement.

So from this:

```
DROP TABLE TEST_TABLE_1234;
```

I want this:

```
TEST_TABLE_1234
```

(without the semicolon)

I have a script in place for the rest of the columns that I inherited, I am just concerned about this new column and how to split the string based on STEP_ID = 1 for each set of tables, and fill down the table name in the new TEST_TABLE_NM column.

Any ideas?  Thanks

Comment: Quick and dirty version: `a.split()[-1][:-1]`, where `a` is your string (`DROP TABLE TEST_TABLE_1234;`). This doesn't check for any edge cases, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could do  `str.replace("DROP TABLE ","")`

Then

```
 str.replace(";","")
```

Comment: Thank you that works, I just need to figure out how to fill down for all the rows in each table.  That works for the first row.  Ill keep digging